# Python how to use salesforce metadata api to add custom fields

Tags: python, salesforce, metadata

I am unable to find any reference for doing so. Is it even possible?

Comment: Am struggling with this myself... Did you work it out? There is this link on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083300/how-to-create-a-custom-table-in-salesforce-using-beatbox-or-simple-salesforce